# How to insert three Chinese characters?

Tags: cjk

I am a rank novice in TeX. I read an earlier TeX question about how to display Chinese characters but it seemed to be in context of an article entirely in Chinese.

My document is an English article in TeX, and I only want to insert three Chinese characters. Can someone tell me how to format it?

Comment: You added xecjk tag, are you using xetex  or are you using classic tex or pdftex, the answer will be different depending which engine you are using.

Comment: No I did not add xecjk tag. Someone else did. LaTeX, for a math document.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/5764) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Comment: @LeoLiu: As it is the local custom I will abide by it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My suggestion: include an image (in pdf format) that contain the three characters. Then you don't need to matter whether others have the proper fonts to compile the document.

Of course, you should prepare the image first. You can use:

```
% To produce a pdf image: "name.pdf"
% UTF-8 encoding
% Compile with XeLaTeX
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{SimSun}
\begin{document}

白居易

\end{document}
```

Then you can include the image (`name.pdf`) in your own article:

```
% You don't need any Chinese support here
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

blah blah blah \includegraphics{name.pdf} blah blah

\end{document}
```

---

Maybe you don't have a modern TeX distribution that support XeLaTeX or you don't have proper Chinses fonts for it. Then you can use the alternative document for the image:

```
% To produce a pdf image: "name.pdf"
% UTF-8 encoding
% Compile with PDFLaTeX
% Alternative method, if you don't have any proper Chinese TTF/OTF font installed
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{CJK}
\begin{document}
\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{gbsn}
白居易
\end{CJK}
\end{document}
```