# xeCJK and Chinese Characters

Tags: cjk, xecjk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Displaying pinyin over Chinese characters, without impacting word spacing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38455/displaying-pinyin-over-chinese-characters-without-impacting-word-spacing)

I'm trying to use xeCJK and I'm having some issues.  This is my code; it comes out very strangely:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\usepackage{ruby}
\renewcommand\rubysize{0.4}
\setCJKmainfont{BiauKai}
\begin{document}

\noindent 床前明月光，疑是地上霜。举头望明月，低头思故乡。 \
\noindent\ruby{床}{chuáng}\ruby{前}{qián}\ruby{明}{míng}\ruby{月}{yuè}\ruby{光}{guāng}，\ruby{疑}{yí}\ruby{是}{shì}\ruby{地}{dì}\ruby{上}{shàng}\ruby{霜}{shuāng}。
\ruby{举}{jǔ}\ruby{头}{tóu}\ruby{望}{wàng}\ruby{明}{míng}\ruby{月}{yuè}，\ruby{低}{dī}\ruby{头}{tóu}\ruby{思}{sī}\ruby{故}{gù}\ruby{乡}{xiāng}。
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please, is this question also by you? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79066/how-to-insert-three-chinese-characters If so, it means you've created two StackExchange accounts. Moderators can merge these acounts in such case.

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. And, maybe you are interested in [Displaying pinyin over Chinese characters, without impacting word spacing](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38455/)

Comment: Please say what is wrong with your output.  Perhaps you are unhappy with the vertical placement of punctuation?