# How do I typeset unicode characters with TexShop?

Tags: unicode, texshop

I've tried pasting "圍棋 (wéiqí)" into my editor, but after typesetting I see only "?? (wiq)" in the PDF. What do I need to change to fix these characters?

Answer (score 5):

You need to use an TeX engine (XeTeX or LuaTeX) that handles Unicode input correctly and a font that contains the characters.  You also need to make sure that your file is saved as UTF-8.

See the following questions for help on these issues:

- [How to insert three Chinese characters?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/79066/2693)
- [How does one type Chinese in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17611/2693)
- [Using XeLaTeX instead of pdfLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21736/2693)
- [Frequently loaded packages: Differences between pdfLaTeX and XeLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2984/2693)
- [The differences between TeX engines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13593/2693)

Answer (score 1):

You can try the {CJKutf8} package according to this [blog](http://denkenblog.blogspot.com/2007/12/using-chinese-in-texshop.html).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{CJKutf8}

\begin{document}
\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{gbsn}
围棋 (wéiqí)
\end{CJK}
\end{document}
```

Note that, because of the fonts, the traditional Chinese character "圍" is not correctly displayed. So I am using the simplified Chinese character "围" here.